# How do I set up parsely with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, validation, parsley, multi-step

I've been working on form validation for days. I'm trying to validate a multi step form.

I'm using Nodejs, ES6, Express, PUG. I'm having a hard time finding something that works. I think parsley would do it for me, but I cant get it to work with NodeJS.

For the code in my .js file (Where risk-calc is the id of my form):

```
$('.form-navigation .next').click(function() {
  if ($('#risk-calc').parsley().validate({group: 'block-' + curIndex()}))
    navigateTo(curIndex() + 1);
```

My console error is '$(...).parsley is not a function.'

I've installed via NPM parselyjs and jquery.

edit.

Attempting to use webpack to add global variables.

Something is still wrong, but how does this look?

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      parsley: 'parsleyjs/dist/parsley.js'
    }),
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question that will return a specific answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I updated the topic as my specific question. Thank you for the response.

Comment: How did you include Parsley in your HTML code? Looks like only jQuery was loaded there.

Comment: You will only need to provide the `jQuery` and `$` variables through the `ProvidePlugin`. Then in your entry js file right at the top you should import `parsleyjs` before using it in the file. This would attach the `parsleyjs` method to the global jquery object. You can just do `import 'parsleyjs'` without a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to include the parsely javascript code after you include the jquery code. That will then extend the jquery object to have the `parsely` method.

If you have imported both through npm then you will need import the `parsleyjs` module at the top of your main entry file for you javascript before bundling it. I would recommend using webpack for the bundling.

```js
import 'parsleyjs'
```

Usually jQuery can be added to your project files globally through the webpack provide plugin.

See: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/

```js
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm looking at webpack now. I'm not sure where to insert your code from above.  Should it go inside the config item?

Comment: The `webpack.ProvidePlugin` code above should go in the `plugins` array of the config (see: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/plugins)

Comment: Are you using webpack to bundle your code? If not then you can watch a tutorial about webpack here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzdEpgONurw

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I will play around with this. I'm going to mark your answer as correct for now.

Comment: Updating my response with some code. Maybe you could take a look at it?

Comment: I added a comment above